# Why not use instanceof operator in OOP design?

Tags: oop, instanceof

It has been repeatedly said that the instanceof operator should not be used except in the equals() method, otherwise it's a bad OOP design.

Some wrote that this is a heavy operation, but it seems that, at least java, handles it pretty well (even more efficiently than Object.toString() comparison).

Can someone please explain, or direct me to some article which explains why is it a bad design?

Consider this:

```java
Class Man{
  doThingsWithAnimals(List<Animal> animals){
    for(Animal animal : animals){
      if(animal instanceOf Fish){
        eatIt(animal);
      }
      else if(animal instanceof Dog){
        playWithIt(animal);
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The decision of what to do with the Animal, is up to the Man. Man's desires can also change occasionally, deciding to eat the Dog, and play with the Fish, while the Animals don't change.

If you think the instanceof operator is not the correct OOP design here, please tell how would you do it without the instanceof, and why?

Comment: Your code is a mess in the first place: why does Man decide to play with the Dog in the method feedAnimals?

Comment: @SimeonVisser you are right, I changed the method name.

Answer (score 18):

`instanceof` simply breaks the [Open/Close principle.](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html) and/or [Liskov substitution principle](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html)

If we are not enough abstract because of `instanceof` usage, each time a new subclass makes an entrance, the main code gathering the logic of the application might be updated.
This is clearly not what we want, since it could potentially break the existing code and reduce its reusability.

Therefore, a good usage of polymorphism should be preferred over the basic use of conditional.

Comment: You apparently disagree with Josh Block on that one ... http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch17.html

Comment: This article deals with another subject, strictly not linked with the open/closed principle.

Comment: Okay, but what about Liskov?

Comment: `instanceof` does not inhererently break either of those principles. It's just sloppy usage of it that does so (but that could be said for pretty much any language feature).

Answer (score 11):

There's a good blog post called [*When Polymorphism Fails*](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails) which is about this kind of scenario. Basically, you're right that it should be up to the `Man` to decide what to do with each kind of `Animal`. Otherwise, the code becomes fragmented and you end up violating principles such as [Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

It wouldn't make sense to have code such as e.g. the following:

```java
abstract class Animal {
    abstract void interactWith(Man man);
}
class Fish extends Animal {
    @Override
    void interactWith(Man man) {
        man.eat(this);
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    void interactWith(Man man) {
        man.playWith(this);
    }
}
```

In that example, we're putting `Man`'s logic outside of the `Man` class.

The problem with `instanceof` is that if you have a large amount of `Animal`s, you'll end up with a long `if-else-if` for every one of them. It's hard to maintain and prone to errors where e.g. a new type of `Animal` is added, but you forget to add it to the `if-else-if` chain. ([The visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is partly a solution to the latter problem, because when you add a new type to the visitor class, all of the implementations stop compiling and you're forced to go update them all.)

However, we can still use polymorphism to make the code simpler and avoid `instanceof`.

For example, if we had a feeding routine such as:

```java
if (animal instanceof Cat) {
    animal.eat(catFood);
} else if (animal instanceof Dog) {
    animal.eat(dogFood);
} else if (...) {
    ...
}
```

We could eliminate the `if-else-if` by having methods such as `Animal.eat(Food)` and `Animal.getPreferredFood()`:

```java
animal.eat(animal.getPreferredFood());
```

With methods such as `Animal.isFood()` and `Animal.isPet()`, the example in the question could be written without `instanceof` as:

```java
if (animal.isFood()) {
    eatIt(animal);
} else if (animal.isPet()) {
    playWithIt(animal);
}
```

Comment: The problem with your `getPreferredFood()` call is that the type system will not prevent you from doing `dog.feed(cat.getPreferredFood())`. This is a fundamental limitation of object-orientation.

Comment: Arguably, the point to using type systems is to prevent wrong operations (e.g., feeding onions to a cat) from even being attempted.

Comment: But lets say one Man likes to playWith Dogs, and not with Cats - would you replace the isntanceof operator with something else? is the instanceof operator wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` is a type system escape hatch. It can be used to do really evil things, like make generics not really generic, or extend a class hierarchy with ad-hoc virtual methods that never appear in the visible interface of those classes. Both of these things are bad for long-term maintainability.

More often than not, if you find yourself wanting to use `instanceof`, it means that there is something wrong with your design. Breaking the type system should always be a last resort, not something to be taken lightly.

I do not think your particular example warrants using `instanceof`. The object-oriented way to do this is to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
abstract class Animal {
  def accept(v: AnimalVisitor)
}

trait Edible extends Animal {
  def taste : String
  def accept(v: AnimalVisitor) = v.visit(this)
}

trait Pet extends Animal {
  def growl : String
  def accept(v: AnimalVisitor) = v.visit(this)
}

abstract class AnimalVisitor {
  def visit(e: Edible)
  def visit(p: Pet)
}

class EatOrPlayVisitor {
  def visit(e: Edible) = println("it tastes " + e.taste)
  def visit(p: Pet) = println("it says: " + p.growl)
}

class Chicken extends Animal with Edible {
  def taste = "plain"
}

class Lobster extends Animal with Edible {
  def taste = "exotic"
}

class Cat extends Animal with Pet {
  def growl = "meow"
}

class Dog extends Animal with Pet {
  def growl = "woof"
}

object Main extends App {
  val v = new EatOrPlayVisitor()
  val as = List(new Chicken(), new Lobster(), new Cat(), new Dog())
  for (a <- as) a.accept(v)
}
```

**NOTE:** I am aware that Scala has case classes, but I wanted to provide a general object-oriented solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But your code does a different thing then mine. The problem arises when Man gets an array of Animals, and he chooses by some logic to eat some, and to playWith some. When you Eat them all, and playWith them all, there is no problem, and also in my implementation I wouldn't have to use instanceof operator...

Comment: @user1028741: I am going to update my answer. Please wait. :-)

Answer (score 0):

using instance of is a bad practise because in the OOP there is no need to check what the class is,
if the method is compatible you should to be able to call it with such arguments, otherwise design is spoiled, flawed,
but it exist the same way as goto in C and C++,
I think sometimes it might be easier to integrate a bad code using instance of but if you make your own proper code avoid it
so basically this is about of programming style what is good and what is bad,
when and why
in some curcumstances bad style is used, because sometimes the code quality is secondary, perhaps
sometimes the goal is to make the code not easy to understand by others so that would be the way to do it

Comment: The user did not imply that his subclasses had different interfaces. You just reiterate that using instanceof is bad design without describing how his task to differentiate instances by class should be implemented. There are enough valid used cases. E.g. think about creating a histogram for the incidence of subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Radiodef’s answer, it occurred to me that the argument between `instance of` and a `isXXX()` method may be related to the [Problem_of_universals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_universals), where philosophers explore the topic about "Whether universals can be considered exist?", or in the OOP context, should you emphasize the judgement itself(should you eat this animal or should you play with it) so much, that making it into an entity(like a intentionally defined method), so that you can manage it easier later.

If you threat the judgement like it doesn't exist in itself, and only rely on the [subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(philosophy)) to judge, then maintaining a bunch of `instance of` in each subject make the most sense.

Otherwise, emphasize the judgement as a method in an interface or even further, emphasize it as a separate interface as isekaijin's answer does.

The point is, these designs are at the cost of complexity(readability, number of classes and layers of invocation) and in exchange for easy management later.

Maybe philosophy seems a little out of topic here. IMHO, the relation between objects in OOP, especially in domain driven designs, benefits from careful modeling of real life relations and even modeling of the cognitive model of the development team members.