# Method return value depending on implementation type

Tags: java

I have a programm with the following structure

- `abstract class A`
- `class B extends A`
- `class C extends A`

So `class A` has two different implementations.

Now i have a generic method in `abstract class A`

```
protected ReturnType doStuff() {
    //THe Return Type is the Problem
}
```

If i use this Method in `class B` i want it to return an Object of `class B`
and the same in `class C`

Question: How do i set the ReturnType to B or C?
Are generics the right way to go? I tried it, but it felt wrong, cause they are both subtypes of A. 
Or should i return 'class A' and cast accordingly? That also felt wrong

Comment: Just set return type to `Object`.

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi - NO!. generics was introduced to *prevent exactly what you are trying to say*

Comment: Yes..generics are the best :D @TheLostMind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following

```
abstract class A<RT extends A> {
    protected abstract RT doStuff();
}

class B extends A<B> {
    // doStuff must return a B
}

class C extends A<C> {
    // doStuff must return a C
}
```

Comment: I was thinking - *wouldn't it be better just to return `A`. Any method call would be delegated to the appropriate object (`B` or `C` ) right?*

Comment: @TheLostMind In the case of builders in particular, it's often useful to know the actual return type.  `B` or `C` may have additional methods not on `A`.

Comment: @chrylis But what's the point then? You know the exact type anyway if you hold a variable of (static) type `B`. You know you will get `B` from invoking `B.doStuff()` when using the inheritence approach as well. I mean, why is it "better" to declare variable of type `A<B>`, rather than `B`.

Comment: @chrylis - Oh. So, if there is a necessity to *know the type / concrete class*, then this approach is the way to go. Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `abstract class A<RT extends A<RT>>`? Or do you want to use the `A` in `extends A` as a raw type? But I guess, this doesn't matter much. Here is another example for the [F-bounded polymorphism](https://s2gatev.com/f-bounded-polymorphism-in-java/).

Answer (score 2):

Java support co-variance in return type of method.

You can declare the abstract method as:

```
protected abstract A doStuff();
```

And there is no problem in returning something that extends `A`:

```
protected B doStuff() { ... }
protected C doStuff() { ... }
```

---

It is perfectly safe, since if invoking:

```
A a = new B();
A res = a.doStuff();
```

`B` extends `A`, so there is no problem doing everything you can do with "regular" `A` with the co-variant type as well.

Comment: with this approach i need to implement `doStuff()` in `class B` and `class C` ? This is what i want to avoid, since it does exactly the same except return the expected Type

Comment: @Dude You are not going to have much of a choice, since `B.doStuff()` and `C.doStuff()` return an object of different type in the first place, you will have to implement them both, or at the very least implement some other `protected abstract` method that differs in the object it returns, and invoke it from `A.doStuff()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do it like this.

```
A result = doSomeStuff();
```

this will return A but it will be an instance of the class that its been called. Class A will return the original class. and if you call another method in the abstract class which is overriden by superclasses. the overriden method will be called and not the method in abstract class. Ofcourse if you want you can also cast it to the instance type.

If you do not want to check the type you can use reflection...

```
protected A doSomeStuff()
{
    A a = null;
    try
    {
        a = this.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
    catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return a;
}

/*
protected A doSomeStuff()
{
    if (this instanceof B)
    {
        return new B();
    }
    else if (this instanceof C)
    {
        return new C();
    }

    return null;
}
*/
```

Comment: i dont want to use a hardcoded if else construct, because there can be more implementations of this class in the future and i dont want to change this code part every time, but thanks for the effort

Comment: You might want to read this: [Why not use instanceof operator in OOP design?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20589590)