# Get type of elements in List

Tags: java, list, generics

I have two different Lists:

```
List<MyFirstClass> list1;
List<MySecondClass> list2;
```

Now I need a method taking a `List` as input. The stuff I do in this method is almost the same for both lists and just slightly different. Since I can't just overload them, I did this:

```
private String myMethod(List<?> myList) {...}
```

But now I need to check what type `?` is, to make the slighly differences in the method in relation to which list-element-type is given.

How do I do this? Or is there any better way to do this?

Thanks!

**Edit**
The two methods are really the same except **one** method call `list1.method1()` and  `list2.method2()`. That is why I don't want to make two different methods.

Comment: `instanceof` is your lead

Comment: What is the slight difference?  Do you intend to call methods specific to `MyFirstClass` and `MySecondClass`?  Something in common to both classes?

Comment: @rgettman Yes, I need to call a method and the name of this method is different for both Classes.

Comment: The need to check `?` in a generic is a pretty good tell that the method is not an ideal candidate for being generic in the first place. You would be better off with two methods, which could perhaps share common logic by calling a common private method.

Comment: It's hard to answer meaningfully without more code.

Comment: @Yahya No, `instanceof` is your enemy. It leads to fragile OOP, hard to extend and error prone programs. Please do not encourage learning developers to depend on `instanceof`.

Comment: @M.leRutte If so, it wouldn't still exist in Java, it's not even deprecated! If you re-read OP question again, you can see the reason why OP doesn't want to overload methods (though I'd prefer method overloading)!

Comment: @progNewbie While there may be multiple ways to solve it, without some more code there is a great risk you are posting a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), in which case the advice you receive may solve the trick, but not in a way that will actually benifit you on the long term.

Comment: @Yahya See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589590/why-not-use-instanceof-operator-in-oop-design The fact that it 'still exists' is not an argument in favor.

Comment: @M.leRutte Agree in case of inheritance, but how did you know that `MyFirstClass` and `MySecondClass` are siblings?

Comment: @Yahya I would love to overload them. But it just does not work, because the parameter-list would be the same.

Comment: I gave an answer below, but I would also say that this is the kind of question that usually indicates a larger problem with your program design that can't really be diagnosed without understanding your program better. You might want to reframe the question with more specifics about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: The need to use `instanceof` is a definite [code smell](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and the answers/comments suggesting a interface or inheritance are really the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal solution is to use `instanceof` to differentiate between the types of objects.

```
private void myMethod(List<?> list) {
    for(Object o : list) {
        if(o instanceof MyFirstClass) {
            MyfirstClass p = (MyFirstClass)o;
            p.myFirstMethod();
        } else if(o instanceof MySecondClass) {
            MySecondClass p = (MyFirstClass)o;
            p.mySecondMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

And if the *design constraints* of your project are immutable, this is your best solution.

### But a better solution uses Inheritance

This problem does demonstrate that you almost certainly have a flaw in your overall design. If you don't/can't know in advance whether you'll get a `List<MyFirstClass>` or `List<MySecondClass>`, then that's pretty strong evidence you have a poorly defined problem domain. It's much better to enforce the necessary constraints by making them implement an interface that instructs how behavior should differ in this situation.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void invokeMyMethod();
}

public class MyFirstClass implements MyInterface {
    public void invokeMyMethod() {myFirstMethod();}
    /*...*/
}
public class MySecondClass implements MyInterface {
    public void invokeMyMethod() {mySecondMethod();}
    /*...*/
}

//In some other class...

private void myMethod(List<MyInterface> list) {
    for(MyInterface o : list) {
        o.invokeMyMethod();
    }
}
```

`myMethod` could also be rewritten in this scenario where you're not sure whether you'll get `List<MyFirstClass>`, `List<MySecondClass>`, or `List<MyInterface>`:

```
private <T extends MyInterface> void myMethod(List<T> list) {
    for(MyInterface o : list) {
        o.invokeMyMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use inheritance to solve your problem.  To do so, make both classes inherit from a common base class (or interface).  Then make a List to store elements of the sub classes.  Store the special logic that is specific to each type within the sub classes.  Here is an example:

```
class BaseClass {
  public void foo() {}
}

class ClassA extends BaseClass {
  public void foo() { /* ClassA logic here */ }
}

class ClassB extends BaseClass {
  public void foo() { /* ClassB logic here */ }
}

List<BaseClass> list = new ArrayList<BaseClass>();
list.add(new ClassA());
list.add(new ClassB());
for(BaseClass element : list) {
  element.foo();
}
```

Comment: Note that I haven't used Java in quite some time, so that might not be 100% valid Java syntax.  If not, hopefully you can adapt that to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't adjust your method directly based off of what the type in `List<?>` is. There are other ways of getting what you want, though. Here's one way (these names are going to be awful because I don't have a lot of context for what you're trying to do):

```
interface MethodCaller<T> {
  void callMethod(T target);
}

class Class1Caller implements MethodCaller<MyFirstClass> {
  @Override
  public void callMethod(MyFirstClass target) {
    target.method1();
  }
}

class Class1Caller implements MethodCaller<MySecondClass> {
  @Override
  public void callMethod(MySecondClass target) {
    target.method2();
  }
}
```

Then change your method to take a `MethodCaller` of the same type as the list, like so:

```
private <T> String myMethod(List<T> myList, MethodCaller<T> methodCaller) {
   // wherever you'd call your method, instead use methodCaller.callMethod() instead
}
```

Now to call your method you'd use `myMethod(list1, new Class1Caller())` or `myMethod(list2, new Class2Caller())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda to extract the distinct call and pass it as an argument to your method:

```
private <T> myMethod(List<? extends T> myList, Consumer<T> method) {
    for (T item : myList) {
        // some stuff
        method.accept(item);
    }
}
```

Then simply call it like this:

```
myMethod(list1, MyFirstClass::method1);
myMethod(list2, MySecondClass::method2);
```

This assumes you're calling 0-arg, `void` methods. If that's not the case, you can use a lambda instead, and/or use one of the other [standard functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) or create your own.

Note that this is essentially a more concise version of [@jacobm's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50359041/1553851).

Answer (score 0):

While you could use `.getClass()`, `instanceof`, or a `Class` parameter, those tend to result in ugly, fragile code.  Please don't go there if you can help it.

### Method #1

The best approach is to use an abstract class or interface to put the required logic into the list items.  The list objects would directly perform whatever operation is required.

The original post seems to indicate that this isn't possible, so let's go on to method 2.

### Method #2

Use a function parameter.

```
public <T> String myMethod(List<T> myList, Function<T, String> func)
```

The function will act on each item in the list, and return something your method can handle.

### Method #3

Use wrapper classes.  You can wrap each list item inside classes that know how to handle them.  The wrapper classes would all inherit from a single base class, allowing your method to look like this:

```
public String myMethod(List<Wrapper> myList)
```