# How to find the largest Count of Objects assosiated with the same Object

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, graph, java-stream

I have a `Mentor` class in which I have an `ID` for each mentor and an `ArrayList` of mentee `ID`s, like this:

```
public class Mentor {
    
    int mentorId;
    ArrayList<Integer> mentees = new ArrayList<>();

    public Mentor(int mentorId, ArrayList<Integer> mentees) {
        this.mentorId = mentorId;
        this.mentees = mentees ;
    }
}
```

The problem is that some *mentees* can be *mentors* too.

I would like to somehow get a ***count*** of all of the *mentees* associated to the top *mentor* as well as how many mentors are under the top mentor.

So, basically, if a *mentor* has a *mentee*, who is also a *mentor*, then this *mentor*'s *mentees* are also associated to the *top mentor*.

So, my thinking was to loop through the *mentee-list* and see if any of the id's match an `ID` of `Mentor`. If true, Add this mentor's list of mentees to a list and loop again, but this will not work dynamically.

My main class looks something like this:

```
    ArrayList<Mentor> mentors = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> mentees = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> mentees2 = new ArrayList<>();

    mentees.add(2);
    mentees.add(3);
    mentees2.add(4);
    mentees2.add(5);

    //[1,{2,3}]
    mentors.add(new Mentor(1, mentees));
    //[2,{4,5}]
    mentors.add(new Mentor(2, mentees2));
    int mentorCount = 0;
    int menteeCount = 0;
    for (Mentor mentor : mentors) {

        for (Integer mentee : mentees) {
            mentorCount++;
            if (mentee == mentor.mentorId){
                mentorCount++;
                //add each mentee to arraylist and start the process again, but is there an easier way to do this.
            }
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way of solving this, maybe using **streams**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's briefly recap the task.

*You have a set of mentors, each mentor has a collection of mentees. Some of them might happen also to be mentors and so on.*

#### Class design

From the perspective of class design, the solution is pretty simple: you need only one class to describe this relationship - `Mentor`. And each `Mentor` should hold a reference to a collection of `Mentor`s (not integer ids).

In your domain model, as you described it, there's no substantial difference between a mentor and a mentee. Mentor points to other mentors - is a simplest way to model that. Mentee is just an edge case, a mentor which has an empty collection of mentors.

You don't need to include classes and features in your application that doesn't bring benefit.

#### Data structure

From the perspective of data structures, this problem can be described very well with an *acyclic disjointed* **Graph**.

*Acyclic* because if we consider the relationship between mentors when a mentor could indirectly point at themself (i.e. a mentor `N` has a mentee, with in tern points to another mentee that happens to be also a mentor of mentor `N`) the task becomes ambiguous. Therefore, I'm making an assumption that no one can be a mentor to himself.

I also depicted this data structure as *disjointed* because mentors in this model (*as well as in real life*) can form isolated groups, which in graph theory called *connected components*. That means that there could be several mentors with the same count of mentee, which happens to be the largest.

#### Depth first search

In order to find all the vertices (*mentors*) connected with a particular mentor, we have a classic traversal algorithm, which is called *Depth first search* (DFS). The core idea of DFS is to peek a single *neighbor* of the given *vertex*, then in turn peek one of its *neighbors* and so on until the hit the *vertex* that doesn't point to the other *vertex* (i.e. maximum depth is reached). And then it should be done with every other *neighbors* of the previously visited *vertices*.

There are two ways to implement DFS.

**Iterative approach**

For that, we need a *stack*. It will store all unvisited *neighbors* of the previously encountered *vertexes*. The last *vertex* from each list of *neighbors* in every *branch* will be explored first because it will be placed on the top of the *stack*. Then it will get removed from the *stack* and it's *neighbors* will be placed on the *stack*. This process repeats in a loop until the *stack* contains at least one element.

The most performant choice of collection for the stack is `ArrayDeque`.

Because this approach require continuous modification of the *stack* by adding and removing *vertices*, it isn't suitable to be implemented with Stream IPA.

**Recursive approach**

The overall principle is the same as described above, but we don't need to provide a stack explosively. The call stack of the JVM will be utilized for that purpose.

With this approach, there's also some room to apply streams. For that reason, I've chosen the recursive implementation. Also, its code is probably a bit easier to understand. But keep in mind that recursion has certain limitations, especially in Java, and not suitable for processing a large set of data.

#### Recursion

A quick recap on recursion.

Every recursive implementation consists of two parts:

- **Base case** - that represents a simple edge-case for which the outcome is known in advance. For this task, the *base case* is the given *vertex* has no *neighbors*. That means `menteesCount` of this vertex needs to be set to `0` because it has no *mentee*. And the return value for the *base case* is `1` because this *vertex*, in turn, is a valid *mentee* of another *vertex* that holds a reference to it.
- **Recursive case** - a part of a solution where *recursive calls* a made and where the main logic resides.

*The recursive case* could be implemented using *streams* and entails recursive invocation of the for every *neighbor* of the *given vertex*. Each of these values will contribute to the `menteesCount` of the *given vertex*.

The value returned by the method will be `menteesCount + 1` because for the *vertex* which triggered this method call, the *given vertex* will be a *mentee* as well as its *mentees*.

#### Implementation

Class mentor basically serves as a vertex of the graph. Each vertex has a unique `id` and collection of adjacent vertexes.

Also, in order to reuse values obtained by performing DFS I've added a *field* `menteesCount` which is initially initialized to `-1` in order to distinguish between *vertices* that has no *adjacent vertices* (i.e. `menteesCount` has to be `0`) and *vertices* which value wasn't calculated. Every value will be established only ones and then reused (*another approach will be to utilize a map for that purpose*).

Method `getTopMentors()` iterates over the collection of *vertices* and invokes DFS for every *vertex* which value wasn't calculated yet. This method returns a list of *mentors* with the highest number of associated *mentees*

Method `addMentor()` that takes a *vertex id*, and *id* of its *neighbors* (*if any*) was added in order to interact with the *graph* in a convenient way.

Map `mentorById` contains every *vertex* that was added in the *graph* and, as its name suggests, allows retrieving it based on the *vertex id*.

```
public class MentorGraph {
    private Map<Integer, Mentor> mentorById = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void addMentor(int mentorId, int... menteeIds) {
        Mentor mentor = mentorById.computeIfAbsent(mentorId, Mentor::new);
        for (int menteeId: menteeIds) {
            mentor.addMentee(mentorById.computeIfAbsent(menteeId, Mentor::new));
        }
    }
    
    public List<Mentor> getTopMentors() {
        List<Mentor> topMentors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Mentor mentor: mentorById.values()) {
            if (mentor.getCount() != -1) continue;
            performDFS(mentor);
    
            if (topMentors.isEmpty() || mentor.getCount() == topMentors.get(0).getCount()) {
                topMentors.add(mentor);
        
            } else if (mentor.getCount() > topMentors.get(0).getCount()) {
    
                topMentors.clear();
                topMentors.add(mentor);
            }
        }
        return topMentors;
    }
    
    private int performDFS(Mentor mentor) {
        if (mentor.getCount() == -1 && mentor.getMentees().isEmpty()) { // base case
            mentor.setCount(0);
            return 1;
        }
        
        int menteeCount = // recursive case
            mentor.getMentees().stream()
                .mapToInt(m -> m.getCount() == -1 ? performDFS(m) : m.getCount() + 1)
                .sum();
        
        mentor.setCount(menteeCount);
        return menteeCount + 1;
    }
    
    public static class Mentor {
        private int id;
        private Set<Mentor> mentees = new HashSet<>();
        private int menteesCount = -1;
        
        public Mentor(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        
        public boolean addMentee(Mentor mentee) {
            return mentees.add(mentee);
        }
    
        // getters, setter for menteesCount, equeals/hashCode
    }
}
```

An ***example*** of the *graph* used as a *demo*.

[image]

`main()` - the code models the graph shown above

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MentorGraph graph = new MentorGraph();

    graph.addMentor(1, 3, 4);
    graph.addMentor(2, 5, 6, 7);
    graph.addMentor(3, 8, 9);
    graph.addMentor(4, 10);
    graph.addMentor(5, 11, 12);
    graph.addMentor(6);
    graph.addMentor(7, 13, 14);
    graph.addMentor(8);
    graph.addMentor(9, 16, 17, 18);
    graph.addMentor(10);
    graph.addMentor(11, 18);
    graph.addMentor(12);
    graph.addMentor(13);
    graph.addMentor(14, 19, 20);
    graph.addMentor(15);
    graph.addMentor(16, 21, 22);
    graph.addMentor(17);
    graph.addMentor(18);
    graph.addMentor(19);
    graph.addMentor(20);
    graph.addMentor(21);
    graph.addMentor(22);
    
    graph.getTopMentors()
         .forEach(m -> System.out.printf("mentorId: %d\tmentees: %d\n", m.getId(), m.getCount()));
}
```

**Output**

```
mentorId: 1 mentees: 10
mentorId: 2 mentees: 10
```

Comment: Thank you, although, it was a lot of work to move the class structure around but this seems to be the only way of working. Many thanks for also providing in depth knowledge of what is happening as well.

Comment: Thanks for your recognition. In regard to class design, if you don't consider that mentor and mentee will have a different behavior in your app, then no need to define different classes for them. Don't take a pill if you don't have a headache) If you *need to distinguish between them* - give them different functionality, is also **OK**. In this case, `MentorGraph` will deal with the parent type only. Class casts with `instanceof` checks is a code smell and needs to be avoided ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644357/17949945 ). When you are using inheritance, you should benefit from polymorphism

Comment: Thanks for the further details. I was wondering if there is a way to get the number of branches who have branches. So, for-example, for the graph 2, we have, '5, 7, 11, 14'. So, a method which should return 4 in this case.

Comment: @mrkn0007 Sorry for the accidental blank message. *get the number of branches who have branches* - in other words, to obtain the number of vertexes that point to other vertexes. That's simple. You can use either depth first search or depth first search algorithm for that. That's how to do it with DFS iterative, create stack, introduce a counter-variable and add all children of the given vertex on the stack. Then in the loop while the stack isn't empty remove the element from the top of the stack and if it has children increment the counter and add all it's children on the stack.

Comment: @mrkn0007 Code `Deque<Mentor> stack = new ArrayDeque(); // add all mentee of the target vertex on the stack`, then `int count = 0;`, explore graph until stack is not empty `while (!stack.isEmpty()) {Mentor current = stakc.pop(); if (current.getMentee().size() > 0) { count++; // all mentee on the stack }}`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using good object oriented design, you shouldn't just use integer id's like that, because in this situation you could simply make an ArrayList of Person objects Where Mentees, and Mentors Inherit from Person. Then you can check if a Person is an instance of Mentee versus Mentor:

```
for (Person p : people) {
    if (p instanceof Mentor)
    {
        // Mentor logic
    }
    if (p instanceof Mentee)
    {
        // Mentee Logic
    }
}
```

Comment: agree with @acornTime, it is better to use OOPs approach. This usecase is typical Composite design pattern candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Person` and `Mentor` and `Mentee` subclasses as suggested by [acornTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71831752/3992939), define `mentees` as a list of `Person` and the information you want becomes simple to get:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        ArrayList<Person> mentees = new ArrayList<>();

        mentees.add(new Mentee(11));
        mentees.add(new Mentee(12));
        mentees.add(new Mentor(2, new ArrayList<>()));
        mentees.add(new Mentee(13));
        mentees.add(new Mentee(14));
        mentees.add(new Mentor(3, new ArrayList<>()));
        mentees.add(new Mentor(4, new ArrayList<>()));
        mentees.add(new Mentor(5, new ArrayList<>()));

        Mentor mentor = new Mentor(1, mentees);

        System.out.println(mentor.menteesCount());
        System.out.println(mentor.mentorsInMentees().count());
    }
}

interface Person {
    int getId();
}

class Mentor implements Person{

    private final int mentorId;
    private List<Person> mentees = new ArrayList<>();

    public Mentor(int id, ArrayList<Person> mentees) {
        mentorId = id;
        this.mentees = mentees ;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return mentorId;
    }

    public List<Person> getMentees() {
        return mentees;
    }

    public int menteesCount() {
        return mentees.size();
    }

    public Stream<Person> mentorsInMentees(){
        return mentees.stream().filter(m -> (m instanceof Mentor));
    }
}

class Mentee implements Person{

    private final int menteeId;

    public Mentee(int id) {
        menteeId = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return menteeId;
    }
}
```

Test it online [here](https://replit.com/@c0derrepo/Mentor#)

Comment: Thank you, this does work, in this manner. However, when I try to make each class in it's own separate .java file, the compiler gives error on Line 12 in MainClass.java that it is expecting Mentee whereas the value being provided is Manager.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. What is `Manager` ?  Did you add the required imports  ?

Comment: I linked a runnable example

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to write Mentor.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like a depth-first or breadth-first search (*):

- Maintain a `Set<Integer>` containing all the people you have already seen.
- Maintain a queue of some kind (e.g. an `ArrayDeque`), of people you are going to check.
- Put the first person (or any number of people, actually) into this queue.
- Then, while the queue is not empty:

  - Take the next person in the queue
  - If you've already seen them, go to the next item in the queue
  - If you've not already seen them, put the person into the seen set; add all of their mentees into the queue

That's it. The number of people at the end is the size of the seen set.

---

(*) Whether you do depth-first or breadth-first search depends on which end of the queue you add mentees to: adding them to the same end that you remove them from results in depth-first search; adding them to the other end results in breadth-first search. If you don't care which, choose either.